# Mutate implicit "Context" parameter

Tags: scala, akka, slick, akka-http, scala-cats

I have application that build on akka-http and slick. All services works with slick `DBIO` instances which transforms into `Future` in the routes classes.
Implicit parameter widely used through services to pass context about current request (user id, permissions etc.) Typical methods signature looks in following way:

```
def getProject(id: ProjectId)(implicit context: Context): DBIO[Project] = {???}
```

Everything was fine until this context was readonly.
Now I have a requirement to implement [domain events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/microservice-ddd-cqrs-patterns/domain-events-design-implementation) approach and dispatch events only after transaction commit. So I decided to store list of events in context and fire them after successfully transforming `DBIO` into `Future`.

My question is how properly mutate this implicit context through different service methods in functional way?
I thought about using [State monad transformer](https://typelevel.org/cats/datatypes/state.html), but it feels that it bring more complexity cause all services already build over `DBIO`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you consider using Cats Effect, you could use Ref to store events.

```
val events: F[Ref[F, List[DomainEvent]]] = Ref.of[F, List[DomainEvent]](Nil)
// assuming that you'll make F=DBIO and provide necessary type class instances

def getProject(id: ProjectId)(implicit events: Ref[DBIO, List[DomainEvents]]): DBIO[Project] = for {
  ... // database actions
  _ <- events.update(list :+ event)
} yield ...
```

Then before running transaction:

```
for { 
  result <- ... // your queries, where you pass events 
  eventList <- events.get
} yield (result, eventList)
```

Ref acts like an atomic wrapper around some data and uses effect defined by you to provide some safety.

There are other options:

- ignoring referential transparency and just passing mutable data structure
- using some monad transformer like StateT or WriterT

What you pick is a matter of preference.